# process multiple streams in videofile with one call

Tags: hash, ffmpeg

I'm working on an video-processing script, which has to process large video files (100 - 500 GB) using ffmpeg.
The video file contains 9 streams:

1 video streams and 8 audio streams.

Now I like to calculate the sha256 hash for each stream. This works fine for a single stream, like this:

```
ffmpeg -i /my/video/file -map 0:v -f hash -hash sha256 -
```

This should generate the sha256 hash from stream 0 (video).

I could loop that command for all streams, which would result in reading and processing that file 9 times.

Is there a way to read that file once and  process all 9 bitstreams parallel?
I like to avoid reading that file from disk againg and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recent* git version of ffmpeg, run

```
ffmpeg -i in -map 0 -f streamhash -hash sha256 -
```

This will print a hash per stream of the form,

```
0,v,SHA256=84dd5b99e1b5fa8877e3365d1a24056ae37c7b3e17a7ab314ec33dbd5034687d
1,a,SHA256=c2ac1a155d451405dbedb0a999e801676e45fb2d17c8025da7c035cc1e8fff92
```

*( > 20 Sep 2019 )

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm waiting / looking for. I miss this feature in alternative paid products!